# How to send a deep link with Firebase Cloud Messaging push notification in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a fully functioning iOS app with push notifications sent through Firebase Cloud Messaging. I also have fully functioning deep links working. I would like to be able to send a push notification that will open one of my deep links. How can I do this so that it works when the app is in the foreground and background, as the onMessageReceived callback only works while in the foreground? Also, I would like to continue to send messages through the Firebase Console, so it would be ideal if I could send it is a key-value pair, but it seems like some people have had issues with that in the past. Does anyone have advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iPhone, when the app is in the foreground, the onMessageReceived callback is not called for FCM push notifications. To handle push notifications with deep links when the app is in the foreground or background, you can use the **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method in your AppDelegate.

Yes, You can send key-value pairs in your FCM push notification payload using the Firebase Console. Just need to add the key-value pair in the data section of the message payload.

Please follow the below link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application

Comment: I ended up using a simular approach. In case anyone else looks at this, I used the userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) method (which does work in the foreground and background). Then I was able to get the actual value I wanted by using: response.notification.request.content.userInfo["<key>"], and I could load my content using that value.